# Express how to pass value from .js promise to .ejs view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, ejs

Im trying to pass a value from a route js file (auth.js) to a ejs view (dashboard.ejs)

this is the code inside auth.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const google = require('googleapis').google;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const CONFIG = require("../config/passport-google");

const nf = require('node-fetch');

const router = express.Router();

// Google's OAuth2 client
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

router.get("/youtube", function(req, res) {
  // Create an OAuth2 client object from the credentials in our config file
  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]
  );

  // Obtain the google login link to which we'll send our users to give us access
  const loginLink = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline", // Indicates that we need to be able to access data continously without the user constantly giving us consent
    scope: CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.scopes // Using the access scopes from our config file
  });
  return res.render("./home/g-login", { loginLink: loginLink });
});

router.get("/youtube/callback", function(req, res) {
  // Create an OAuth2 client object from the credentials in our config file
  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]
  );

  if (req.query.error) {
    // The user did not give us permission.
    return res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) return res.redirect("/");

      // Store the credentials given by google into a jsonwebtoken in a cookie called 'jwt'
      res.cookie("jwt", jwt.sign(token, CONFIG.JWTsecret));
      
      // return res.redirect("/get_some_data");

      if (!req.cookies.jwt) {
        // We haven't logged in
        return res.redirect("/");
      }
    
      // Add this specific user's credentials to our OAuth2 client
      oauth2Client.credentials = jwt.verify(req.cookies.jwt, CONFIG.JWTsecret);
    
      // Get the youtube service
      const service = google.youtube("v3");

      const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${token[Object.keys(token)[0]]}`;

      const get_data = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await nf(url);
          const json = await response.json();
          return await json;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };

      const diomerda = get_data();

      module.exports = {
        diomerda
      }
      
      // Get 50 of the user's subscriptions (the channels they're subscribed to)
      service.subscriptions
        .list({
          auth: oauth2Client,
          mine: true,
          part: "snippet,contentDetails",
          maxResults: 50
        })
        .then(response => {
          //console.log(response.data.items[0].snippet.resourceId)

          // Render the profile view, passing the subscriptions to it
          return res.render("./user/dashboard", { subscriptions: response.data.items, diomerda: diomerda });
        });

    });
  }
});

// Logout from Google
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
})

module.exports = router;
```

the diomerda variable is a promise, and i'm already rendering the view via the function below service.subscriptions (which correctly sends the value of subscriptions to the dashboard view) so how can i also pass my diomerda variable to that view?

i'm trying with `module.exports` as you can see in the code but it seems i can't use `require` inside ejs files

dashboard.ejs is:

```
<h6>Profile dashboard</h6>
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<p>Here are your favorites channels</p>
<% var params = require('../routes/auth')   
    console.log(params.diomerda);
  %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the mark1 and mark2 in the following code.

mark1: you don't need to export this method, just use it before render your ejs view. And when you return your json in this function, you don't need to add extra await here.

mark2: I place the `get_data` function in here because I saw you render ejs to user at the end of code in `router.get("/youtube/callback")`. So, before render ejs view to user, you need to call `get_data` function to get the data you want. Then, just render it with data.

```js
router.get("/youtube/callback", function(req, res) {
    // Create an OAuth2 client object from the credentials in our config file
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
      CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id,
      CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret,
      CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]
    );
  
    if (req.query.error) {
      // The user did not give us permission.
      return res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, function(err, token) {
        if (err) return res.redirect("/");
  
        // Store the credentials given by google into a jsonwebtoken in a cookie called 'jwt'
        res.cookie("jwt", jwt.sign(token, CONFIG.JWTsecret));
        
        // return res.redirect("/get_some_data");
  
        if (!req.cookies.jwt) {
          // We haven't logged in
          return res.redirect("/");
        }
      
        // Add this specific user's credentials to our OAuth2 client
        oauth2Client.credentials = jwt.verify(req.cookies.jwt, CONFIG.JWTsecret);
      
        // Get the youtube service
        const service = google.youtube("v3");
  
        const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${token[Object.keys(token)[0]]}`;
  
        // ================ mark 1 ====================
        const get_data = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await nf(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            return json;
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        };
  
        // Get 50 of the user's subscriptions (the channels they're subscribed to)
        service.subscriptions
          .list({
            auth: oauth2Client,
            mine: true,
            part: "snippet,contentDetails",
            maxResults: 50
          })
          // ================ mark 2 ====================
          // remember to add async here
          .then(async (response) => { 
             // ================ mark 2 ====================
             const diomerda = await get_data()
  
            // Render the profile view, passing the subscriptions to it
            return res.render("./user/dashboard", { subscriptions: response.data.items, diomerda: diomerda });
          });
  
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi, what you mean by "// require it in your service subscriptions" , service.subscriptions is already inside auth.js, all the code above is inside auth.js

Comment: the "service" is a variable declared right above the code i shown, with const service = google.youtube("v3"); because I required "googleapis" inside my auth.js

Comment: I thought it’s different file. could you paste the full js file?

Comment: edited with the full code. the reason why i'm doing this is because the youtube v3 api doesn't return user infos, so i had to use the token i got from youtube oauth and use it to do a userinfo api call, and the async js shitfest begun

Comment: Thanks you're awesome. I also understood better the logic of async/await with your marks.

Comment: Do you eventually know why after my first try now is throwing an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No refresh token is set.  ?